# UWP - Middle Mouse Wheel Button Click Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, uwp

I have a button control that when clicked with mouse wheel, should do something.

I tried this from WPF but I think it's different in UWP.

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle)
    {
        button6.Content = "Hi";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `PointerPressed` event handler on `Button`.

Usage:

```cs
private void Button5_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Button);
    if (pointer.Properties.IsMiddleButtonPressed)
    {
        button6.Content = "Hello";
    }
}
```

### Update

Add `PointerReleased` event handler on UIElement, but not `Button`, I think Button's Click event overrides the middle mouse up event.

Usage:

```cs
private void Grid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
    if (pointer.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.MiddleButtonReleased)
    {
        // Todo
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: This is very cool and it works. Is there a way to trigger it when the pointer is released instead of pressed?

Comment: Yes, but not on the Button. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `Pointer` event and handle mouse device events

```
        BUtton_1.PointerPressed += delegate(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args) 
        {
            Pointer ptr = args.Pointer;
            if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse) // Wheel click has just on mouse
            {
                Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = args.GetCurrentPoint((Button)sender);
                if (ptrPt.Properties.IsMiddleButtonPressed)
                {
                    TextBox_1.Text += "Hi";
                }
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        };
```